# Re-factoring the usage of same switch-case multiple time

Tags: java, refactoring, switch-statement

In a class I have following switch-case:

```
switch(articleStep.getDeveloper()) {
    case CENTRAL:
        switch(articleStep.getArticleType()) {
            case POSM:
                //some code
                break;

            case PROMOTION_PACK:
                //some code
                break;
        }
        break;

    case LOCAL:
        //some code
        break;
}
```

in multiple methods. Only the internal operations differ among them (`//some code`).

Is there any alternate way exists by which I can place the switch-case in only one method, and I will call that method by passing the operations as parameters, and it will do the same job?

---

**Usage-1**

```
switch(articleStep.getDeveloper()) {
    case CENTRAL:
        switch(articleStep.getArticleType()) {
            case POSM:
                centralPOSMArticle = new AddManageArticleInDTO<ManageCentralPOSMArticleInDTO>();                
                centralPOSMArticle.setManageArticle(new ManageCentralPOSMArticleInDTO());
                setMandetoryParameterToAddManageArticleInDTO(centralPOSMArticle);
                break;

            case PROMOTION_PACK:
                centralPromotionPackArticle = new AddManageArticleInDTO<ManageCentralPromotionPackArticleInDTO>();                
                centralPromotionPackArticle.setManageArticle(new ManageCentralPromotionPackArticleInDTO());
                setMandetoryParameterToAddManageArticleInDTO(centralPromotionPackArticle);
                break;
        }
        break;

    case LOCAL:

        break;
}
```

**Usage-2**

```
switch(articleStep.getDeveloper()) {
    case CENTRAL:
        switch(articleStep.getArticleType()) {
            case POSM:
                genericDTO = centralPOSMArticle.getManageArticle();
                break;

            case PROMOTION_PACK:
                genericDTO = centralPromotionPackArticle.getManageArticle();
                break;
        }

        break;

    case LOCAL:

        break;
}
```

There are total seven place where I have used this type of switch-case.

Comment: Depends on what your `// some code` does.

Comment: @fge I have added two usage of the switch-case, please see the update.

Comment: In your example, does the scope of `genericDTO` include  the calling code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find your idea quite unworkable, but a good approach would be to define methods inside your enum and rely on dynamic dispatch to do the work of your switch statements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please elaborate the "dynamic dispatch to do the work of your switch statements"?

Comment: The Enum class is not in my hand. I cannot add method in that Enum.

Comment: Well, if it's outside your control, then this won't work. Dynamic method dispatch is fundamentally a switch statement on the object type.